# The proper approach to generate components based on API data

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-ui-router

I have a structure in my project that is something like this :
[image]

Footer and header are nested views.

`index.html`:

            `<div data-ui-view="header"></div>
             <div data-ui-view="main"></div>
            <div data-ui-view="footer"></div>`

routing:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'header': {
                    component: 'headerComponent'
                },
                'footer': {
                    component: 'footerComponent'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('index.home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'main@': {
                    templateUrl: 'boxesTemplate.html'
                }
            }
        });
```

The main section should include boxes (that are probably components?), as you can see at the screenshot. But the number of boxes and their content (like box heading) should be generated by data that is pulled from the backend using $http. I want to use component to communicate with API.
Can I achieve this somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest solution - ng-repeat and ng-include

```
<custom-component 
    ng-repeat="config in $ctrl.components" 
    service="$ctrl.service"
    config="config">
</custom-component>
```

where component is something like:

component('customComponent', {
   ....
   template: ''
}

and any appropriate api-service realization, which will be used by included template.